# Loop through values and add to range

Tags: loops, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Column A includes a list of vendors. The vendors may be repeated. Eg: A2=Vendor1, A3=Vendor2, A4=Vendor1, A5=Vendor3, A6=Vendor2 etc.

Column B includes the payout made to each vendor. Eg: B2=5000, B3=2000, B4=1000, B5=6000 etc.

Is there any way to compute total payout made to Vendor1, Vendor2, Vendor3 etc?

Comment: .:use `query()`

Answer (score 0):

A little meat on [@I'-'I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685690/loop-through-values-in-google-spreadsheet-and-add-to-range#comment88382088_50685690)'s Comment:

```
 =query(A:B,"select A, sum(B) group by A")
```